# Correct way to access commonly used code blocks from single class at Swift

Tags: ios, swift, code-reuse

I want to implement a helper class for some constant values and also commonly used code blocks. Between below usages, which one is the correct way?

1. Defining them as static let values
2. Defining them as class functions

   ```
   class Constants 
   {
       // 1: defining them as static let values
       static let storyboardA = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardA", bundle: nil)
       static let storyboardB = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardB", bundle: nil)
       static let rootVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!!.rootViewController

      // 2: OR defining them as class functions
      class func getStoryboardA() -> UIStoryboard {
         return UIStoryboard(name: "storyboardA", bundle: nil)
      }

      class func getStoryboardB() -> UIStoryboard {
         return UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardB", bundle: nil)
      }

      class func getRootVC() -> UIViewController? {
         return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!!.rootViewController
      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Your examples do different things (instantiating a new one instance vs. using the same over and over again). I'd go with the methods, and cache reused objects within private variables.

I'd highly recommend **against** using this approach, though. It looks tempting at first, but it brings huge costs along with it in the long wrong. It makes for very tight code coupling and poor code reuse. Testing will be much harder.

Your helper class will get bigger and bigger, and it doesn't have a single "topic". It's responsible for the most different things within your app. It's unlikely that you need the storyboard for one part in your app in many other parts etc.

Most of the time, if you need to access those things all over the place your app design would profit from some refactoring. For example, you should rarely if ever need to access the application delegate. It's a convenient "reference point" that's easily available to pester it with code that really does not belong their (been there, done it, learned my lesson).

A slightly more sound approach is to make individual helper classes and throw them into the using classes, and I wouldn't make their members class methods either.

Comment: >>"instantiating a new one instance vs. using the same over and over again" . Could you be more specific? As far as I know `static let` will be instantiated only once

Comment: @AnilVarghese Yes, and the given class methods will in contrast return new objects.

Comment: Oh you mean, you would use methods in such a way that it returns private static variables. more like combines both approaches of OP. May you could show some sample code, will be more helpful